# MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I'm coming from a MS SQL Server background.
Working on a new project using MySQL with NaviCat 8 Admin tools.
Ok, here's the question.
Normally when working in MS land if I want to update some data I use a stored procedure to do this:

```
Drop Procedure spNew
Create Procedure spNew (@P_Param)

UPDATE Table
SET Field = 'some value'
WHERE ID = @P_Param
```

I am trying to do this same logic from within NaviCat.
I defined the Parameter, `(IN '@P_Param' int)`

In the Definition i placed:

```
BEGIN
     UPDATE Table
     SET Field = 'some value'
     WHERE ID = @P_Param
END;
```

When I try and save the stored procedure, i'm getting this error:
"1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax, blah, blah, blah"

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNew(P_Param INT)
BEGIN
     UPDATE Table
     SET Field = 'some value'
     WHERE ID = P_Param;
END;
```

Note that `MySQL` syntax and overall ideology are *very* different from those of `SQL Server`.

You may also need to set delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spNew(P_Param INT)
BEGIN
     UPDATE Table
     SET Field = 'some value'
     WHERE ID = P_Param;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

BTW, I'm assuming you don't actually call your table `"Table"`, since it's a reserved word.

If you do, you need to enclose it into backticks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spNew(P_Param INT)
BEGIN
     UPDATE `Table`
     SET    `Field` = 'some value'
     WHERE  `ID` = P_Param;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I realize the ideologies are very different.
Logic-wise though I was able to jump right in and understand what I'm doing for the most part.
After removing the '@' I am still getting a syntax error.

Comment: Still no dice with the Delimiter.
Is it safe to say that Stored Procedures are not used by the masses often in MySQL?

Comment: It is safer to say that `NaviCat 8` is not used :) I just reproduced it on `Query Browser` (shipped with `MySQL`), everything's OK.

Comment: Ha, this is funny.  The backticks looked like single quotes to me.
Fixed.
Thanks a ton Quassnoi!
:-D

Answer (score 0):

Parameters to MySQL stored procedures aren't prefixed with @ or quoted in either the declaration or when used.  Local variables are prefixed with @, however.

Try:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spNew;
CREATE PROCEDURE spNew(IN P_Param INT)
BEGIN
     UPDATE Table
     SET Field = 'some value'
     WHERE ID = P_Param
END;
```